# What features distinguish the true diphthongs of English?

Tags: english, phonology, american-english, diphthongs

How are the true diphthongs of English distinguished from each other and other vowels with traditional distinctive features theory?

Comment: What is meant here by "true" diphthongs?   For example, do you mean "phonemic" diphthongs?

Comment: Also the various Englishes have different repertoires of diphthongs.

Comment: Yes, by "true" diphthongs, I mean those that are distinctive/phonemic, i.e. /aɪ/, /aʊ/, and /oɪ/.

Comment: I'm thinking of standard North American English.

Answer (score 0):

In American English, the "true" diphthongs are considered to be

- /ay/, as in *I, by, buy, try, five, tie, lye, hi, high*, and *jai alai*
- /aw/, as in *ow, bough, how, brown, snout, out, trowel*, and *sauerkraut*
- /oy/, as in *soil, toy, coin, Troy, ploy, oink,* and *hoi polloi*

All of these are complex vowel clusters, starting at a phonemic low vowel (/o, a/), and continuing with a gesture toward a high front vowel /i/, represented as a semivowel /y/, or towards a high back vowel /u/, represented as a semivowel /w/.

The "untrue" diphthongs are the tense vowel phonemes /i, e, o, u/, which are predictably terminated by a gesture toward /i/ (for /e, i/) and toward /u/ (for /u, o/). These are not marked as diphthongs in Kenyon and Knott's transcription of American English phonemics, because they're predictable.

As for distinctive features, the precise representation depends on which version of "distinctive feature" theory one wishes to use, and what its constraints and presuppositions are. Consult your phonology instructor for details.

Comment: I should have been more precise in my question. I'm thinking of traditional Sound Pattern of English (SPE) features. I don't think the contrast can be captured in this framework. But even in a non-linear framework where the vowel can be represented as occupying two slots within the nucleus, if one were to try to use features to represent this, would it be [+low],[+high,-back] for /aɪ/ and [+low],[+high,+back] for /aʊ/?

Comment: A close reading of SPE will reveal that they actually do have an extensive treatment of the English diphthongs. Non-linear representations (as you propose) aren't different from SPE representations in this case. The SPE analysis of these diphthongs as deriving from /ī, ū, œ̄/ is compatible with nonlinear theory, and the only reason we wouldn't say that now is that we better understand the flaws in the original argument.